# How do I use visual studio 2017's Install class to package a program and package a driver at the same time?

Tags: c#

Can someone help me? Although I have learned how to use the Install class to install my program, I do not know how to install a driver at the same time.My program runs with the support of a driver. I need my installer to be able to install both the program and the driver at the same time.

I already have the driver installation script,But I don't know how to write the code for the install class, what can I do to achieve my purpose?

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    LogWrite("Install！");
    base.Install(stateSaver);
}
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    LogWrite("OnBeforeInstall!");
    base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
}
public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    LogWrite("Uninstall!");
    base.Uninstall(savedState);
}
public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
{
    LogWrite("Rollback");
    base.Rollback(savedState);
}
public void LogWrite(string str)
{
    string LogPath = @"c:\log\";
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(LogPath + @"SetUpLog.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ") + str + "\n");
    }
}
```